# Oracle DB Query : To compare only the last two inserted rows?

Tags: oracle

Imagine if I have a table as below :

**DEPARTMENT_INFORMATION**

```
Id      Dept_Id     Dept_Name   Date_time
---------------------------------------------
001     100         AAA         13-JUN-14
002     100         BBB         14-AUG-14
003     100         AAA         16-SEP-14

004     101         CCC         02-JUL-14
005     101         DDD         08-JUL-14
006     101         DDD         18-AUG-14

007     102         EEE         20-AUG-14
008     102         FFF         16-AUG-14
009     102         GGG         21-AUG-14
```

### STEP -1 :

I NEED TO FILTER BASED ON THE DEPT_ID (100,101,102) AND GET THE LAST TWO INSERTED COLUMN BASED ON DATE_TIME AS BELOW :

```
Id      Dept_Id     Dept_Name   Date_time
----------------------------------------------
002     100         BBB         14-AUG-14
003     100         AAA         16-SEP-14

005     101         DDD         08-JUL-14
006     101         DDD         18-AUG-14

007     102         EEE         20-AUG-14
009     102         GGG         21-AUG-14
```

### STEP -2 :

I NEED TO COMPARE THE DEPT_NAME FOR SAME DEPT_ID AND
QUERY 1:  IF IT IS SAME ONLY THE DEPT_ID HAS TO BE DISPLAYED .. 
QUERY 2:  IF IS IS DIFFERENT THE DEPT_ID HAS TO BE DISPLAYED..

SO BASICALLY TWO QUERIES IS NEEDED :

### EXPECTED_OUTPUT :

*If it is same :*

```
DEPT_ID 
--------
101
```

*If it is Different:*

```
DEPT_ID
-------
100 
102
```

HOW DO I ACHIEVE THIS ?

Basically what i tried was comparing all three Dept_Name and displaying if there is difference in all three and vice-versa.. 
But i wanted to compare only the last two inserted  record for that Dept_Name and Display the Dept_Id ..

Comment: Mysql and oracle are 2 different things.

Comment: @Mihai yeah, just kidding. user1614043, edit your question and keep only the correct tag. Do you use MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: @Mihai.. Thanks for editing.. First time user ;)

Comment: @ypercube : I use Oracle..

Answer (score 0):

The following query might help you:

```
select distinct Dept_Id
from  
( select * 
  from (select * from DEPARTMENT_INFORMATION order by Dept_Id) 
  order by Date_time ) 
where ROWNUM <= 2;
```

Comment: This query displays the Dept_id no matter the last two Dept_name is same or different ..

Comment: And also it is not considering the latest inserted two rows for that Dept_id.. i wanna compare the recently inserted two rows .. AS given in STEP -1

Comment: Thanks for ur help.. 
Well the above edited query too has the same result.. I need two different output(Basically two queries) .. one  for same Dept_name and one for difference in Dept_name :(